# static method declaration in abstract class

Tags: java, static-methods, abstract

I am trying to write a static method inside an abstract class, and as per my understanding, it is legal to create static methods under abstract class. However, the factory class I am trying to create keeps giving me the error: Illegal static declaration in inner class.

```
public abstract class Employee{
    protected String name;
    protected int hours;

    public String getName(){
        return name;
    }
    public int getHours(){
        return hours;
    }

    public abstract String getType();

    public Employee(String name, int hours){
        this.name=name;
        this.hours=hours;
    }

    public abstract double totalPay();


    public static Employee factory(String name, String type, int hours, double wage, double salary){
        if(type.equals("SALARIED")||type.equals("Salaried")||type.equals("salaried")){
            Employee object=new SalariedEmployee(salary, name, hours);
            return object;
        }
        else if(type.equals("HOURLY")||type.equals("Hourly")||type.equals("hourly")){
            Employee object=new HourlyEmployee(wage);
            return object;
        }
        else{
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't return anything in your first 2 condition blocks inside the `factory` method.

Comment: And most importantly, this line: `public abstract class Employee{` appears twice in your class.

Comment: Ok, what is going on here?  You keep editing your code?  Did you post your actual code?  Or just something else entirely that is not relevant to your problem?

Comment: I am sorry, I edited it wrong, and was fixing problems you guys were pointing out. But the problem persists

Comment: Did you actually try the code that you corrected above in your IDE? If so, please point the exact line where the error appears and make sure it's the same error that you said it was.

Comment: public static Employee factory(String name, String type, int hours, double wage, double salary) 
is the line I am having the error in.

Comment: Is the file name for your class - Employee.java ?

Comment: tip: instead of:  if(type.equals("SALARIED")||type.equals("Salaried")||type.equals("salaried")) use type.equalsIgnoreCase("salaried") method.

Comment: What error are you getting now?  Is it still `Illegal static declaration in inner class`?  If not, that would be the important part to let us know.

Comment: Welcome , though ideally the error for that should be - 'class Employee is public, should be declared in a file named Employee.java'

Comment: @RickyYang after understanding all the comments and the answers for this, I created the Salaried and the Hourly sub classes. I had to add an empty `public Employee(){ }` constructor in the `Employee` abstract class for the whole thing to work. Did you do that?

Answer (score 1):

Filename of the class was not Employee.java , for public classes, the file which houses the class needs to be named - .java . In OP example - Employee.java .

Though the error that comes when a public class is defined in a file with a different name is -

```
class Employee is public, should be declared in a file named Employee.java
```

Answer (score 0):

Inner class cannot have a static member

> As with instance methods and variables, an inner class is associated with an instance of its enclosing class and has direct access to that object's methods and fields. Also, because an inner class is associated with an instance, it cannot define any static members itself.

For reference: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html

Comment: That's right information as per the docs in the link but the OP's question isn't about inner/nested static class, it is rather about static method.